# Supertabular : help with bottom margins and title

Tags: tables, supertabular

I am writing a 3 page long table with latex supertabular.
At the top of the first page, there is a title. Then starts the 3 page long table.

I am facing 3 issues :

- First, my bottom margin does not exist anymore. The table goes until the end of the page, overwriting page number.
- Second, the table is starting on a new page, leaving on the previous page the title.
- Third, texts in some of the lines are too long and should be split into two lines. Right now I am doing this :

```
Text 1 & Super long text part 1 \\
& Super long text part 2 \\
```

But Im sure there is a way to do this automatically.

Here is my tabular :

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{librecaslon}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{supertabular}


\Huge \centering TABLE DES ABRÉVIATIONS \\
\vspace{1cm}
\small
\begin{center}
\begin{supertabular}{rl}

Test & Test \\
Test & Test sometimes longer than a full line \\
Test & Test \\
Test & Test \\
Test & Test \\
Test & Test \\

\end{supertabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It is, off course, much longer.

Thank you all in advance for your help !

Comment: With the example code you provided so far, I can't reproduce the issues 1 and 2 that you describe. Regarding issue 3, you might want to use a `p` type column of appropriate width. As an alternative, you could also use `xltabular` and an `X` type column. For a more automated approach to produce a list of abbreviations, there are also packages suh as `glossaries-extra` or `arco`.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your help !
Regarding issues 1 and 2, I didn't wanted to copy and paste a huge table... But I can edit my post.
I have tried xltabular : it solves all issues at once ! Thank you !